# Embedding a webpage link Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I tested my website on server with IE9 when launched it worked fine.

We embedded that website in sharepoint 2010 . Same webpage when opened in Sharepoint 2010 it messes whole webpage.

CSS written on aspx page does not work.

I don't understand why it would work on IE9 on server and local desktop ? and not under one of the tab in sharepoint ?

Let me know if more info is required?

**Note:** Works fine for firefox and Chrome, problem is only with IE?

Answers Appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on "We embedded that website in sharepoint 2010"?

Comment: Thank you for the question. In sharepoint, you can add your weblink a under one of the sharepoint tabs. You can see your webpage when you click on the tab of share point. When I click on the tab of sharepoint it messes up your webpage!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Page Viewer Web Part (Content Editor WP not meant for this):

[Display a Web page on a SharePoint page by adding the Page Viewer Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/display-a-web-page-on-a-sharepoint-page-by-adding-the-page-viewer-web-part-HA101857182.aspx#_Toc282433250)

[How to embed a webpage into SharePoint](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7d5dfe0a-a82a-410e-a742-af278cba3549/how-to-embed-a-webpage-into-sharepoint-)

Comment: Hey Irish, sorry for the late reply.When I changed document mode to IE9 it worked fine. Looks like Sharepoint was set to IE8 comparability only. Now I did set IE9 compatiblity @web.config file for my webpage but still it does not overwrite sharepoint setings. Can some help me with this? how can I overwrite Share point settings  for my webpage only

Comment: You should set the compatibility in the master page. You could do this in SharePoint Designer if you're working without source control. If it needs to go in source control then you need to create a branding project as a Feature in VS 2008 and deploy it as a solution on the WFE server(s).

Comment: I don't have control over Sharepoint and I think I have changed compatiblity of master page too. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hey Man, I tried all possible ways including <head runat="server"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />. Also, I followed this article : http://blog.codefluententities.com/2012/09/28/how-to-enable-ie-9-compatibility-mode-for-your-website/ still have issues with this.

Comment: You'll have to update your question with details of your environment and the exact issues you're having. Be sure to explain tools you used and how you deployed it.

Comment: We decided to go with New Window option in Share point. that solved all the problems. Thanks for your help IrishChieftain!